# Angular Js in Rails not changing state

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-ui-router

I have a rails app with two layouts **application** for landing page and **dashboard** for the backend dashboard. I want to use angular js for the user dashboard alone. Following [this](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/) tutorial, I've integrated angular and the dashboard home state loads when the dashboard is loaded. But when clicked on the voluneers menu, I want the volunteers state to be rendered, But it is not working.

**Dashboard Layout**
*app/views/layouts*

```
 !!!
%html{"ng-app" => "myApp"}
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
    %title Dashboard
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'dashboard', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'dashboard'

  %body
    .animsition
      = render 'layouts/partials/dashboard_sidebar'
      = render 'layouts/partials/dashboard_header'
      %ui-view
```

**Dashboard sidebar menu item Which Should render volunteers state**

```
 <li><a href="#"> <i class="ti-email"></i> <span>Volunteers</span> <i class="pull-right has-submenu ti-angle-right"></i></a>
      <ul class="nav nav-submenu submenu-hidden"> 
        <li><a href="/volunteers">View All</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

**App.js**
*app/assets/javascripts*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','templates' ])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

/**
 * Routes and States
 */
    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboards', {
            url: '/dashboards',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
        .state('volunteers', {
            url: '/volunteers',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

    // default fall back route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboards');

    // enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});
```

**Controllers**
app/javascripts/angular/controllers

*main.js*

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.things = ['Test App'];
    });
```

*home.js*

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.things = ['Test App'];
    });
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require dashboard/raphael-min.js
//= require dashboard/d3
//= require dashboard/jquery-ui.min
//= require dashboard/bootstrap.min
//= require dashboard/jquery.animsition.min
//= require dashboard/epoch.min
//= require dashboard/includes
//= require app
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ../templates
```

Comment: Please let us know what errors you are receiving on console.

Comment: Hi .,@ABPrime I don't see any errors in the console.

Comment: Open view page source of your project window and verify all javascripts files are loaded properly or not. and let us know the location of `home.html` in your project.

Comment: @ABPrime Thanks for your reply. Yes., All the Js files are loaded currectly and even I can change the state if writing a ng-click function. The home.html is places inside app/assets/templates

Comment: as per above link http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/ your home template should be this `app/assets/templates/home.html.erb` .